# Sql Query error ,may be syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck with the query where I want to retrieve followers record along with whom he is following as following_label may be 1 or 0 
so i did for followers and its working very well,

```
SELECT firstname,lastname,type,image,username 
FROM relations
LEFT JOIN users ON relations.subscriber=users.id
WHERE relations.leader=9 
LIMIT 12
```

**relation table structure is id ,subscriber(follower) and leader (parent)**

But now I want to check in the same record whom he is following i.e check if 
subscriber=leader.

so I tried this but unfortunately it does not seem to be working .

```
SELECT firstname,lastname,type,image,username,subscriber as sub 
FROM relations
LEFT JOIN users ON relations.subscriber=users.id
WHERE relations.leader=9 limit 12 AND
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN subsriber = 9 
           THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END as Salable, * 
FROM relations
```

> I  Want to get something like this
>   [soundcloud.com/userid3218377271/followers](https://soundcloud.com/userid3218377271/followers) if you check first three
>   box they are my followers and  if you mouse over them you see even i
>   am following three of them  and the last one m not following so
>   "follow back" button exists in it

Comment: It's quite hard to follow the question as it's currently phrased. Could you please include your tables' structures, some sample data, and the result you'd like to get for this sample data?

Comment: hey,
table structure for relations table is mentioned pls check <
but users its just the columns i mentioned id ,firstname ,lastname,image,type .

Comment: @user3177068 pls add your table structures and designs clearly as suggested.It's difficult to follow from your question.

Answer (score 0):

To get who a user is following and who is following the same user the right command is `UNION` or `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT firstname,lastname,type,image,username,subscriber as sub 
FROM   relations
       LEFT JOIN users ON relations.subscriber=users.id
WHERE  relations.leader=9 limit 12
UNION ALL 
SELECT firstname,lastname,type,image,username,subscriber as sub
FROM   relations
       LEFT JOIN users ON relations.subscriber=users.id
WHERE  relations.subscriber=9 limit 12
```

The query merged with `UNION` or `UNION ALL` need to have the same fields list or, at least, the same field count and the same type for the fields in the same position.

To get who is following a user and if the user is following back a `LEFT JOIN` should do the trick

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, type, image, username
     , s.subscriber as sub
     , ISNULL(fb.leader) followback
FROM   relations s
       INNER JOIN users ON relations.subscriber = users.id
       LEFT  JOIN relations fb ON user.id = fb.leader AND fb.subscriber = 9
WHERE  s.leader=9 limit 12
```

If `followback` is 1 the user is NOT following back the subscriber.
You can change the formula user for `followback` I used a easy one, just to make an example.

Comment: I want to union all with a condition so that if columns meets its 1 else 0 , so that i can get something like this https://soundcloud.com/userid3218377271/followers , if you check first three box they are my followers and if you mouse over them you see even i am following three of them and the last one m not following so "follow back" button in it

Comment: @user3177068 so you need to know who is following a user and if the user is following back, not every who is following a user and who the user is following, right?

Comment: correct,like the reference link .
please help rectifying the query.

Comment: I tried with this now and i think almost close ,but value is repeating and join is not working 
SELECT subscriber as sub,
CASE WHEN relations.subscriber IN ('9') THEN 'heisalsofollowing'
         ELSE 'nonfollowers' END AS Continent
FROM   relations
WHERE  relations.leader=9 OR relations.subscriber=9 limit 12